# How can I reverse an asterisk triangle in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Currently, I have a code that outputs an asterisk triangle like this:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

Here is the code for it:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
for i in range(1,num+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print("*",end=' ')
    print()
```

Now, how can I use/modify the same code above to make the triangle look like this:

```
        *
      * *
    * * *
  * * * *
* * * * *
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This code does not produce the triangle here. I took the liberty to correct it

Comment: you are....correct. o__o let me fix that quickly. I was playing around with it.

Comment: @RafaelC Thank you, that was a very negligent mistake on my part. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the string method [`str.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust):

```
>>> num = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
>>> for i in range(1, num + 1):
...     print(" ".join("*" * i).rjust(num * 2 - 1))
Enter the number of rows: 5
        *
      * *
    * * *
  * * * *
* * * * *
```

Comment: you surprised me with your answer. I have always solved this problem using 2 loops and a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to reverse it and flip it upside down you can use this:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))

for i in range(1, num + 1):
for j in range(1, num + 1):
    if i > j:
        print(' ', end=' ')
    else:
        print('*', end=' ')
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that can do it either way:

```
def tristar(n,rev=False):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if rev:
            s = ' ' * (n-i) + '*' * i
            print(s)
        else:
            s = '*' * i
            print(s)
```

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but did you call the function?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not allowed to use `rjust`:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    for j in range(num, 0, -1):
        if j <= i:
            print('*', end=' ')
        else:
            print(' ', end=' ')
    print()
```

or alternatively:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
for i in range(num, 0, -1):
    for j in range(1, num + 1):
        if i > j:
            print(' ', end=' ')
        else:
            print('*', end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

A `f-string` approach, so a row layout oriented solution. The code holds if the space between each character is one, so each line as a fixed length of `2*num-1`.

```
num = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))

for i in range(1, num+1):
    print(f'{" ".join("*" * i):>{2*num-1}}')
```

Output

```
Enter the number of rows: 5
        *
      * *
    * * *
  * * * *
* * * * *
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code will print a reversed triangle:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print("{:>5s}".format("*"*i))
```

Output:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```