# Printing a pyramid pattern inverse order in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print out this:

```
**********
 *********       
  ********
   ******* 
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

But somehow I get it in the inverse order like upside down
This is my code. I am very confused since the things that I can use are very restrained. I must not use any String method, for loops, slicing-index, or "*" * n, something like that. All I can do is using while and if-else cases.

This is my code, I delve deep into it with trying not to make it useless.

```
outer = 1
while outer <= 10:
    inner = outer
    pos = 10  
    while pos >= 1:
        if pos > inner:  
            print(" ", end=" ")
            pos = pos - 1
        else:
            print("*", end=" ")  
            inner = inner - 1
            pos = pos - 1
    print(" ")
    outer = outer + 1
```

My output is

```
              *  
            * *  
          * * *  
        * * * *  
      * * * * *  
    * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * *  
* * * * * * * *
```

---

---

Thanks.

Comment: You should include the output from your code as it stands now, so we can compare to the expected output. Also, strange that you can use `while` but not `for`. Both are loops.

Comment: This is my homework and I have to do what is given to me as directives. Okay I will add my output

Comment: Related:  [How can I reverse an asterisk triangle in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51388808/674039)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more simplified way to do it:

```
n = 10
while n > 0:
    i = 10 - n
    m = n
    g = 1
    while m <= 10:
        print(" ", end="")
        m += 1
    while g < m - i:
        print("*", end="")
        g += 1
    print()
    n -= 1
```

Output:

```
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

Answer (score 0):

I made another version that I think will work

```py
def pyramid(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        k = 0
        while k < (i):
            print(" ", end="")
            k += 1
        j = i
        while j < n:
            print("*", end="")
            j +=1
        print()
        i += 1

pyramid(10)
```